# How do I apply =If to an existing formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have this formula currently:
=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(MAX(B2:B6),B2:B6,0))

I want to apply this formula if the criteria is something specific in column A. Any ideas how to do it?

Perhaps my initial formula is wrong. Here is an example set of data. I want to see if I'm looking at eg Pizza, on which was the most recent date someone had it and who had it: I've added a picture of my example data.

[image: Food]

---

---

Comment: `IF(A=?, <formula>, result if false)`?

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work. if I needed A="Office" would it be:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will achieve what you want:

```
=INDEX(C$2:C$6,MATCH(MAXIFS(B$2:B$6,A$2:A$6,A2),B$2:B$6,0))
```

(note IIRC, you will need Excel 2016 or a more recent version to use `MAXIFS`)

Comment: It's done it!! Thank you so much, spent far too much time trying to work it out today!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define "something specific in column A" as an expression that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE. That can then become the condition of the IF statement.

for example run the formula only ifthe value in A2  is "office"

```
=if(A2="office",INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(MAX(B2:B6),B2:B6,0)),"")
```

Comment: Perhaps my initial formula is wrong. I've added a picture to my original question. I want to see if I'm looking at eg Pizza, on which was the most recent date someone had it and who had it